# Configure Amazon EC2 for PHP with IIS7

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, amazon-ec2

I have a machine configured for ASP.NET 4 & IIS7.

I want to run PHP on the same machine without interrupting ASP.NET. Anyone know the steps and I will research it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install php for windows. http://php.iis.net/ Its almost the same as installing it on your local machine. It wont interrupt any existing asp.net applications unless you mess with iis and their directories/applications. Amazon should give you access to the ec2 instance to install and configure iis.

[Walkthrough](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/24/running-php-applications-on-iis/).